# What causes NSURLConnection to stop receiving before it's done?

Tags: ios, plist, nsurlconnection

My game needs to fill tableView cells with a bunch of things from my server database.  This has been working fine. Then I upgraded Xcode to 4.6 and targeted iOS6.1, to please the App Review Team folks.  Now, one of my connections never completes.  (All of the other Posts seem to work correctly, as always.)  Here's my post:

```
- (void) fillCells {
    Cell_QtoA *newCell = [[Cell_QtoA alloc] initCellUser:usrID Grp:grpID Qtn:0 Gnm:@"na" Cat:@"na" Sit:@"na" Pfl:@"na" Lks:0 isA:0 ddA:0 ];
    NSMutableURLRequest *reqPost = [SimplePost urlencodedRequestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kFillCells] andDataDictionary:[newCell toDictC]];
    (void) [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:reqPost delegate:self];
}
```

I think it's working fine. The PHP and database haven't changed. Everything worked great yesterday, before the upgrades.  Here's my connection method:

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
   NSLog(@"data = %@", data);
   NSString  *error;
   NSArray *array = (NSArray *)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:data mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:0 errorDescription:&error];
   if( error ) {
       NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
       return;
   }
   NSLog(@"1st object in array of %d is %@", [array count], array );
}
```

Because I suspected net speeds to be an issue, I added a timer to the call, which I never needed before:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(fillCells) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

The timer didn't help.  Still get errors:

```
"Unexpected EOF" and "Unexpected character z (or whatever) at Line 1"
```

The NSLog of data shows hex data that appears cut off, like:

```
<3c3f786d 6c207665 ... 63743e0a 3c2f6172 7261793e 0a3c2f70 6c697374 3e>
```

It's like the reception is being interrupted.  Anyone know what's happening here?  Thanks!

Comment: That delegate method won't receive all the data will it; don't you need to collect it all up **before** calling `propertyListFromData`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't using **all** the response data; as mention in the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate):

> The newly available data. The delegate should concatenate the contents
>   of each data object delivered to build up the complete data for a URL
>   load.

So you need to create an `NSData` instance variable; clear before the request and append to it whenever new data arrives. Then use the `didFinishLoading` delegate method to trigger the call to `propertyListFromData` with the complete response.

Comment: Thanks! Don't know why I hadn't seen this before, but I'm happy now.  Here's a useful [tutorial](http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/)